# How to render slotted ng-template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have custom component `tab`. The template of this `tab` component looks like:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

I use `tab` component like this:

```
<tab>
  <ng-template>
    ...
  </ng-template>
</tab>
```

Inside the `tab` component I have an `Input` parameter. According to this `Input` parameter I want this slotted `ng-template` to be rendered or not. How can I implement this? How can I render this `ng-template` from inside the `tab` component?

Comment: If the input parameter is called `show`, have you tried `<ng-content *ngIf="show"></ng-content>`?

Comment: yes I tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ng-template`, you cannot use `ng-content` to render this. You need to use the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive:

Parent template:

```
<button (click)="show = !show">Toggle</button>

<tab [show]="show">
  <ng-template>
    I am rendered
  </ng-template>
</tab>
```

Child ts:

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef)
  template?: TemplateRef<any>;

  @Input()
  show?: boolean;
}
```

Child template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="show" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"></ng-container>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bpwrbw)

---

Another way would be to leave the showing to the parent component:

Parent template:

```
<button (click)="show = !show">Toggle</button>

<tab>
  <ng-template [ngIf]="show">
    I am rendered
  </ng-template>
</tab>
```

Child template:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

[working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tqf1ao?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

The last answer sounds like it opposes my first answer where I mentioned that you cannot use `ng-content` to render the `ng-template`, but in this case the `*ngIf` is taking care of the rendering of the template.